# Is there an equivalent to GraphicsPath.AddString in .NET Maui?

Tags: c#, 3d, .net-maui

Rendering text in 3D requires the geometry (lines, arcs, curves) making up the paths of a text string in a given font. .NET System.Drawing.Drawing2D has the GraphicsPath.AddString method for that purpose, but that's platform dependent.

I've discovered the PathF class in Maui, but find no similar string functionality there. Any way to get this font geometry data for a string would be helpful, even if through a 3rd party package.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need should be `Geometries` in maui.

The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) `Geometry` class, and the classes that derive from it, enable you to describe the geometry of a 2D shape. `Geometry` objects can be simple, such as rectangles and circles, or composite, created from two or more geometry objects. In addition, more complex geometries can be created that include arcs and curves.

The `Geometry` class is the parent class for several classes that define different categories of geometries:

- `EllipseGeometry`, which represents the geometry of an ellipse or
  circle.
- `GeometryGroup`, which represents a container that can combine
  multiple geometry objects into a single object.
- `LineGeometry`, which represents the geometry of a line.
- `PathGeometry`, which represents the geometry of a complex shape that
  can be composed of arcs, curves, ellipses, lines, and rectangles.
- `RectangleGeometry`, which represents the geometry of a rectangle or
  square.

For more information, you can check document: [Geometries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/geometries)

Comment: I searched the Geometries documents and see no reference at all to the ability to obtain the lines and curves that make up the glyphs of a string in a specified font from these classes. And these are visual controls to build user interfaces, whereas I want the raw data, e.g. for building 3D models of the text.

Comment: There is a feature request here: https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/issues/348.

Comment: While that issue is irrelevant to my search for GraphicsPath.AddString functionality in Maui, perhaps I should add my own issue there as well.

Comment: Yes, you can add your feature request there.